# Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

Getting this error while trying to build linear regression model. But could see all variables are numeric. As I converted categorical into dummy variables few has 0's in it. When I don't apply log(sales) then it works fine.
Facing issue only when i use log(sales). Can someone help me in this please.

```
[Code Snippet][1]
```

Comment: Do you have zero sales? `log(0)` returns `-Inf`.

Comment: Hi Priyanka, welcome to SO. please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and avoid pasting images...

Comment: I don't think it helps you if someone answers the question by posting an image for you :) so please help us to help you

Comment: and you don't do all(is.na(...)) to find if there's any NAs. it should be any(is.na(..))